# Best practices of deploying Spring Extjs webapp

Tags: spring, extjs, deployment

i'm working on a project involving Spring Boot for creating a REST webservice and ExtJS 5 for Front End, Frontend and backend are developped independentely, so i've managed to avoid CORS problems, i would like to know Best practices concerning deployment in this case. i would like to keep the backend independent of the frontend by packaging frontend in its own .war and so for backend, is there any problems in following this practice.

Comment: By frontend, do you mean only the ExtJs resources and static resources not including WEB-INF resources? Would be nice if you elaborate a little.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid CORS problem if you deploy front-end and back-end to the same domain but different context (domain.com/front, domain.com/back).
In other case you need CORS, please take a look at the last release Spring Boot 1.3.M1:
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/12/spring-boot-1-3-0-m1-available-now

> The recently released Spring Framework 4.2 RC1 provides first class support for CORS out-of-the-box, giving you an easier and more powerful way to configure it than typical filter based solutions.

Source post: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework